# How to read depth_registered image in callback?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, image, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to read depth_registered/image_rect image in my callback function as following

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
try
{
    cv_ptr     = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::TYPE_32FC1);
    depthImage = cv_ptr->image.clone();
}
```

I know the image consists of float values in meter. But what I get is really white-black image.

I need to get the depth of a pixel to find 3D position. Can you help me how to read depth or how to find 3d location from pixel directly ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71686/how-to-read-depth_registered-image-in-callback-?/) by [CHz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4559/chz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use imshow() then values <= 0 are black and >= 1 white.
Because of this a typical depth image should be black (distance unknown->0) and white (Distance > ca.1m).

To get the 3D position use:
point.y=(y - centerY) / depthFocalLength;
point.x=(x - centerX) / depthFocalLength;
point.z=depthvalue_at(y,x);

where (x,y) are the coordinates from the depth image and the rest should be calibrated.
I think the default parameter for the kinect camera are:
centerX = 319.5,
centerY = 239.5,
depthFocalLength = 525.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CHz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4559/chz/) on 2013-08-07**:
Thank you very much ! I have read the image as;

cv_ptr     = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg,enc::TYPE_32FC1);
depthImage = cv_ptr->image.clone();

And read the values as float;

depthImage.at(p2D.y, p2D.x) ;

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2014-01-01**:
Is that working? Usually those depth-images are 16bit unsigned integers (cv_16uc1?), not floating point. The value is the distance in mm.

**Comment by [CHz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4559/chz/) on 2014-01-01**:
Yes, it is working well.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2014-03-25**:
@stfn: Just /camera/depth/image_raw is uint16

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-17**:
can you send me your callback function please ?